# Why is my nginx proxy redirection not working?

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I am trying to implement sub-domain to my domain using nginx. I am taking reference of [this](https://gist.github.com/soheilhy/8b94347ff8336d971ad0) article. It helped me redirect to respective port using following syntax:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name example.com;

   location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
   }
}
```

This worked perfectly. But now I want to add a beta subdomain to my domain. for eg. `beta.example.com`. And according to article mentioned above, I added `beta.example.com` to /etc/hosts, added following lines after previous server block:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  beta.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9090;
    }
}
```

However, when I hit the url in my browser, I cannot reach my server at 9090.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you setup DNS for your subdomain ? You say you cannot reach your server by hitting the subdomain url in your browser. 
If you didn't try to add :

```
IpOfYourServer beta.example.com
```

to /etc/hosts on your local machine (assuming you have a unix like system)

Comment: I have only registered the domain example.com in goDaddy. Should I configure beta.example.com in my goDaddy or is it enough to do it from nginx?

Comment: If you want a subdomain (that you can access from everywhere) then configure beta.example.com in goDaddy.

Comment: If you'll only access your server on few machines then you can modify each of their hosts file instead of configuring a "real" subdomain in goDaddy. It's up to you

Comment: Available on each machine you modify hosts file